# Override knockout validation message globally

Tags: validation, knockout.js, knockout-validation

How would i best override the default validation message for a native validation rule (e.g. *required*) so that it applies globally?

Answer (score 0):

create a jquery.validate.extension.js and refer it in your basic bundles.

```js
(function ($) {
    $.extend($.validator.messages, {
        'required': function () {
            return "REQUIRED";
        },
        'email': function () {
            return "Email!";
        },
        'date': function () {
            return "DATE!";
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```